# Determine integers n for which H ={$\alpha \in A_n | ~\alpha^2 = \mathcal{E}\} $ is a subgroup of $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Determine integers n for which H ={$\alpha \in A_n | ~\alpha^2 = \mathcal{E}\} $ is a subgroup of $A_n$, where $\mathcal{E}$ is the identity .

**Attempt** : If $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$  are even permutation $\in H$ such that :

${\alpha_1}^2 = \mathcal{E}$ and ${\alpha_2}^2 = \mathcal{E}$

H is a subgroup $=>$ $\alpha_1 {\alpha_2}^{-1} \in H$

$=> [\alpha_1 {\alpha_2}^{-1}]^2 =  \mathcal{E}$

$=> \alpha_1 {\alpha_2}^{-1}\alpha_1 {\alpha_2}^{-1}=  \mathcal{E}$

$\alpha_1, \alpha_2$  are even permutations $=>{\alpha_2}^{-1}$ is also an even permutation

Hence overall,  $=> \alpha_1 {\alpha_2}^{-1}\alpha_1 {\alpha_2}^{-1}$ is an even permutation which is consistent with the requirements of an identity permutation

Now, order of $  \alpha_1 {\alpha_2}^{-1} = 2$ where $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$   $\in A_n$

How do i move on from here?

Thank you

EDIT: order of $  \alpha_1 {\alpha_2}^{-1} = 2$ where $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$   $\in A_n$

But, since ${\alpha_2}^2=\mathcal{E} =>\alpha_2= {\alpha_2}^{-1}$

=> order of $  \alpha_1 \alpha_2  = 2$

where both $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$   $\in A_n$

Now, i must find $n$ such that $A_n$ contains elements of order $2$.

What can i do next?

Comment: You could try and find an $n$ (I suggest $n=5$) and suitable $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ such that $\alpha_1 \alpha_2^{-1}$ does not have order $2$. That would answer the question in the negative for that $n$ and hence also for all larger $n$. That would leave only a few small $n$, which you could study individually.

Comment: By the way, if $\alpha^2$ is the identity, then $\alpha = \alpha^{-1}$.

Comment: *Hint* Think about commutativity.

Comment: So, uhmm, what i was thinking, that if somewhere i knew $\alpha$'s were made of disjoint cycles, we could have still concluded that all those cycles must be 2 cycle permutations. 
Else, is hit and trial the only way out, i mean checking for values of n and then deciding?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff yeah, i did think about that. 
So, if $A_n$ happens to be commutative, then $(\alpha_1\alpha_2)^2= \mathcal{E}$

So, we know that $S_n$ is non abelian for $n \geq 3$ . Hence, possible answers  are either $n = 1,2$

Comment: @VHP $A_3$ is also abelian. If $n\geqslant 4$; try to come up ith elements $\alpha,\beta$ of order $2$ in $A_n$ that do not commute, let's say products of disjoint transpositions that are not disjoint themselves.